# Using Lazy<> with Prism.DryIoc.Forms gives "container is garbage collected" exception

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism, dryioc

We're using Prism.DryIoc.Forms to create apps with Xamarin.Forms. To minimize the startup time of the app we are using the Lazy<> pattern for classes with a lot of dependencies.

This used to work fine with Prism.Unity.Forms. However, I can't get it to work with Prism.DryIoc.Forms. Any help would be appreciated.

The code is as follows. We have a page view model like this:

```
public class MySamplePageViewModel
{
    private readonly Lazy<ISomeClass> _lazySomeClass;

    public MySamplePageViewModel(Lazy<ISomeClass> lazySomeClass)
    {
        _lazySomeClass = lazySomeClass;
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        _lazySomeClass.Value.DoIt(); //throws exception
    }
}
```

However, after the page view model is being instantiated, when calling _lazySomeClass.Value we get an exception with message "*Container is no longer available (has been garbage-collected).*".
It seems to be related to how Prism resolves the view model, because when calling the following it works fine:

```
var container = (Application.Current as PrismApplicationBase<IContainer>).Container;
var lazySomeClass = container.Resolve<Lazy<ISomeClass>>();
lazySomeClass.Value.DoIt(); //works fine
```

we're doing the registration like this:

```
container.Register<ISomeClass, SomeClass>(Reuse.Singleton);
container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<MySamplePage, MySamplePageViewModel>("MySamplePage");
```

Comment: What is the version of DryIoc itself?

Comment: I'm using DryIoc 2.10.1 because that is the only one I could get to work with Prism.DryIoc.Forms 6.3.0.1.
With higher versions of DryIoc I get

`Could not load file or assembly 'DryIoc, Version=2.12.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.`

when the container is being accessed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem should be fixed in [v2.10.3](https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/wiki/VersionHistory).

Therefore the next logical step is to ask Prism.DryIoc.Forms maintainers to update to the latest DryIoc version.

Comment: Prism 7 already targets a newer version. If you use the latest 6.3 release then you simply need to update DryIoc in your application.

Comment: I tested Prism.DryIoc.Forms version 7.0.0.51-ci which uses DryIoc version 2.10.7 and it worked like a charm. 
@DanS. simply updating DryIoc without updating prism didn't work. It seems that Prism.DryIoc.Forms 6.3.0.1 only works with DryIoc 2.10.1 (and not a higher version)